# Time check spanning 2 days

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I am creating a windows service, which checks folders, other services ect. and sends alert textmessages if any of these are down. However, I am not interested in getting alert messages during a given period of time (from 23.00 evening to 07.00 morning).

The service is set up through an XML configuration file, where this period of silence can be predefined.

I need a method to check if the service is operating in the period of time, so it will suspend text messaging. The service checks for this period every 5 minutes, so I cannot figure out how to cope shifting of days, during these checks.

To elaborate:

My current code:

```
bool silende = false;
DateTime silenceModeFrom = new DateTime(
    DateTime.Now.Year, 
    DateTime.Now.Month, 
    DateTime.Now.Day, 
    int.Parse(doc.XPathSelectElement(
        "//SurveilanceServiceConfig/SilenceModeTimeFrom").Value), 
    00, 
    00);

DateTime silenceModeTo = silenceModeFrom.AddHours(
    int.Parse(doc.XPathSelectElement(
        "//SurveilanceServiceConfig/SilenceModeTimeHours").Value));

if (DateTime.Now > silenceModeFrom && DateTime.Now < silenceModeTo)
{
     silence = true;
}
```

In this code, the check works if it is made before 24.00, but not after as `DateTime.Now.Day` etc., will be the next day. So in theory, code only validates silence period as being from 23.00 to 24.00 per day.

Comment: Why can't you figure this out? What do you mean by shifting of days? Please be more specific!

Comment: Could you elaborate on "*I cannot figure out how to cope shifting of days*" - day's don't shift. Time does based on things like DST.

Comment: What did you try? Compared to writing a windows service and XML configuration, checking if the time component of DateTime.Now is larger than 23:00 or smaller than 07:00 and then NOT doing something seems pretty basic.

Comment: Step 1) Use `DateTime.Now` to check the current time. Step 2) Check said time to see if it's between 11pm - 7am, Step 3) Have a `bool` property that turns off text message based on step 2).

Comment: if(DateTime.Hour > 7 && DateTime.Hour <  23) something on those line might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't that far off...

There is a *slight* issue with your code as it stands, everytime you call `DateTime.Now` the time would have changed - you need to capture that *instance* of time when the service is triggered i.e.

```
var instant = DateTime.Now;
DateTime silenceModeFrom = new DateTime(instant.Year, instant.Month, instant.Day, int.Parse(doc.XPathSelectElement("//SurveilanceServiceConfig/SilenceModeTimeFrom").Value), 00, 00);
DateTime silenceModeTo = silenceModeFrom.AddHours(int.Parse(doc.XPathSelectElement("//SurveilanceServiceConfig/SilenceModeTimeHours").Value));
bool silence = instant.TimeOfDay >= silenceModeFrom.TimeOfDay && instant <= silenceModeTo;
```

Looking at this code though, your time window appears wrong. You aren't really interested in the `Date` at all here - it's really just the time. Therefore, anything between 23:00hrs - 07:00hrs is considered the "silent" period i.e.

```
int curHour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
int silenceStartHour = int.Parse(doc.XPathSelectElement("//SurveilanceServiceConfig/SilenceModeTimeFrom").Value);
int silenceEndHour = int.Parse(doc.XPathSelectElement("//SurveilanceServiceConfig/SilenceModeTimeHours").Value);
bool silence = curHour > silenceStartHour || curHour < silenceEndHour;
```

The logic for determining whether you are in the silent period can be improved slightly to account for a range that is all in one day, or a range that is split over midnight.

```
bool silence = silenceStartHour <= silenceEndHour
    ? (curHour >= silenceStartHour && curHour < silenceEndHour)
    : (curHour >= silenceStartHour || curHour < silenceEndHour);
```

Comment: Very close, but this won't work if the silence range is in the middle of a single day instead of crossing midnight.  That last line needs some additional logic.  Also the start should be inclusive using `>=`.

Comment: @MattJohnson good spot on the start not being inclusive, the end hour should also be inclusive (I had this in the first example). However, I am not sure why you think this wouldn't work if it was within the same day? For example, if my start hour was `9` and my end hour was `17` then anything between `9:00 - 17:00` would be ignored - unless I am missing something obvious...

Comment: Only the start should be inclusive.  In the original example of `23:00 - 07:00`, you wouldn't want `07:30` to be silent (nor `07:00`).  For the `09:00-17:00` example, the current code would consider the entire day to be silent.  For instance, `05:00` is still before `17:00`.

Comment: @MattJiohnson Ah if course...clearly I was missing something obvious :) Thanks